# Why does TFS build "partially succeed" on this line?

Tags: powershell, tfs, npm, continuous-integration

**The Problem**

I'm adding a pre-build script to our TFS build that calls `npm install` among other things. One package, `gulp-imagemin`, installs a few dependencies that each run a test when they install that says they've installed successfully. TFS is interpreting this output as an error even though it's actually a success message. It causes my build to "partially succeed".

[image: TFS Partially succeeded error]

The unrecognizable characters above are supposed to be a checkmark (I can see it when running locally)...apparently TFS is not a fan, but there are other lines in the output where this happens and it doesn't show an error next to it, so I don't think that's the cause.

Here's where that message comes from:
https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/blob/master/lib/install.js#L34

[image: Log message]

Does anyone know why TFS is interpreting this as an error, or how I can fix this? Thanks much!

**What I've Tried**

I've tried to silence its output (by redirecting stdout and stderr to `$null`) to no avail. When running my .ps1 script locally, I can successfully silence that message, but when the script runs in TFS it still gets printed out. I'm not sure what the difference is.

I also tried making my script a .cmd script instead of .ps1 and that had an interesting effect. The silencing I originally intended worked, but then it would effectively skip the step and the remaining pre-build steps. When I removed the output redirect to nul so I could debug, it brought me back to the same error above with no new info.